# Dog biting every dog in her "pack". She is the youngest

Tags: behavior, biting, feral

All are street dogs.She started biting other dogs around her since today afternoon. There are 6 dogs in one circle and 5 in one circle. As told by nearby vendors. All dogs were scared of her and hidden from her. She did not try ot bite any human. Just running towards any dog and just biting non stop. Its she is has lost her mind from daily beating and thrown around by other dogs. If she had rabies she would bite people also. But she is biting only dogs.

Comment: I’m very sorry but: what is your question?

Comment: If you can't tell, when you can watch her, how can we? If it was a pet I'd say get her to a vet; she might be in pain. Street dog? Not sure there's much you can do.